# Авторизация в spring security?

Tags: java, авторизация

Есть необходимость авторизовываться на сайте под разными типами пользователей. Учитель и ученик. Эти пользователи имеют различные @Entity и в одной таблице храниться не могут. Могу ли я разнести их авторизационные данные по разным таблицам? Если да, то как потом указать спринг, из какой именно таблицы следует брать информацию.

Comment: А разве авторизационные данные у них не общие? Это обычно имя, пароль, роль. Это можно в одной таблице хранить же.

Comment: Мне поставили задачу именно из разных баз. Поэтому задаю вопрос, возможно это в принципе невыполнимо?

Comment: я думаю что выполнимо: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686649/how-to-check-multiple-tables-in-spring-security-for-authentication

Comment: Все можно. Можно скормить spring security запрос, который вытащит пользователей через UNION двух таблиц. Можно заимлементить  AuthenticationProvider, который вообще реализует любые ваши пожелания по авторизации. Но хранить юзеров разных типов в виде разных сущностей в разных таблицах в БД - выглядит как архитектурный косяк. Авторизационные данные не стоит смешивать с бизнес-объектами.

Comment: Можете также сделать для учителя и ученика разные ссылки для авторизации, и по каждой ссылке использовать  метод `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication()`